# Trouble accessing dictionary item in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

I'm experienced in Obj-C, but fairly new to Swift. I have a simple function that takes a Set and a Dictionary as parameters:

```
func buildSource(dataToParse:Set<String>, lookupData:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {
    for item in dataToParse {
        for dict in lookupData {
            let nameID = dict["name"] // compile error
        }
    }
}
```

The passed in parameter `lookupData` is a dictionary containing nested dictionaries. I know that each of these dictionaries contains a key called `name` but when I try to access that key using the following syntax:

```
let nameID = dict["name"]
```

I get the following comile error:

```
Type '(String, AnyObject)' has no subscript members
```

If I know that a key exists, how do I access it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Foundation

func buildSource(dataToParse:Set<String>, lookupData:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)->[AnyObject] {
    var ret: Array<AnyObject> = []
    for item in dataToParse {
        for (key, value) in lookupData {
            if key == item {
                ret.append(value)
            }
        }
    }
    return ret
}

let set = Set(["alfa","beta","gama"])
var data: Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = [:]
data["alfa"] = NSNumber(integer: 1)
data["beta"] = NSDate()
data["theta"] = NSString(string: "some string")

let find = buildSource(set, lookupData: data)
dump(find)

/* prints
▿ 2 elements
- [0]: 28 Nov 2015 18:02
▿ [1]: 1 #0
▿ NSNumber: 1
▿ NSValue: 1
- NSObject: 1
*/
```

in your code

```
for dict in lookupData {
    let nameID = dict["name"] // compile error
}
```

dict is not a dictionary, but (key, value) tuple!

Comment: @R Menke it doesn't matter, he can continue further an further, as he want. you know, map on dictionary gives you array of key, value pairs. the same for x in ... forEach  .. etc

Comment: @RMenke he just didn't use item (from his set) for now. "name" is string key in his lookupData (dictionary). for dict in lookupData gives you (key, value) pair . if value is another dictionary, you can continue deeper

Comment: @R Menke by the way, swift Dictionary doesn't conform to AnyObject protocol, maybe deeper is some NSDictionary ...

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

- get value from `lookupData` with `"name"` as the `key`
- downcast to a dictionary with `as? [String:AnyObject]`
- iterate over `dataToParse`
- use the `String` from `dataToParse` to access the nested dictionary.

---

```
func buildSource(dataToParse:Set<String>, lookupData:[String:AnyObject]) {

    guard let dict = lookupData["name"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {
        return
    }

    for item in dataToParse {
        let value = dict[item]
    }
}
```

---

**More possible solutions:**

If lookupData is an array of dictionaries:

```
func buildSource(dataToParse:Set<String>, lookupData:[[String:AnyObject]]) {
    for item in dataToParse { // String
        for dict in lookupData { // dict
            let nameID = dict["name"] // value
        }
    }
}
```

If lookupData is a nested dictionary :

```
func buildSource(dataToParse:Set<String>, lookupData:[String:[String:AnyObject]]) {
    for item in dataToParse {
        guard let dict = lookupData[item] else {
            continue
        }
        guard let nameID = dict["name"] else {
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

If lookupData is definitely `[String:AnyObject]` and it's value might be another `[String:AnyObject]`, but it might also not be.

```
func buildSource(dataToParse:Set<String>, lookupData:[String:AnyObject]) {
    for item in dataToParse {
        guard let dict = lookupData[item] as? [String:AnyObject] else {
            continue
        }
        guard let nameID = dict["name"] else {
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Each string in the set should appear as a value for the 'name' key in the dictionary referenced by 'item'

Comment: Yes, lookupData is a colleciton of dictionaries, each of which has a 'name' key

Comment: @Pheepster Well your lookupData definitely has the wrong type. You are also not using `item` anywhere.

Comment: That's correct, I am not using item, yet. I need to look up the value of item in the dictionary I'm trying to obtain using dict["name"]. The 'name' key will contain the value stored in item

Comment: @Pheepster updated  "The 'name' key will contain the value stored in item" this makes little sense to me